# fatal: Cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle fatal: error [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Tags: android, git, repo

I tried to down android source code.but meet a problem.

```
# repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
fatal: Cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

the Url, I can open it by Chrome,but can not connect in shell. why?
I have did step by step with [this](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html),but I can't repo init success. I have tried almost every solution,but no one can work, what should I do to solve that? thanks you.

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: yes,I using Lantern. thanks for your reminder.So   "export HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:8787"  is worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have met this issue, please try the below commands via proxy.

```
set http_proxy=http://user:pass@host:port
set https_proxy=https://user:pass@host:port
```

if not

```
unset https_proxy
unset http_proxy
```

actually, you can permanently delete or add this proxy in Ubuntu

```
cat /etc/enviroment
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if you are behind a proxy, export these variables or set as "Environment Variables"

```
set http_proxy=http://user:pass@host:port
set https_proxy=https://user:pass@host:port
```

(Both with http)

***SET** in windows **EXPORT** in Linux.

Comment: my second line of error is different : Its SSL Error .( SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] CERTIFICATE VERIFY FAILED(_ssl.c:726) .Can you please help !!

Answer (score 0):

In my case is because of the `http_proxy` environment variable. I check the python code `repo`:

```
def _InitHttp():
  handlers = []

  mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
  try:
    import netrc
    n = netrc.netrc()
    for host in n.hosts:
      p = n.hosts[host]
      mgr.add_password(p[1], 'http://%s/' % host, p[0], p[2])
      mgr.add_password(p[1], 'https://%s/' % host, p[0], p[2])
  except:  # pylint: disable=bare-except
    pass
  handlers.append(urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(mgr))
  handlers.append(urllib.request.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(mgr))

  if 'http_proxy' in os.environ:
    url = os.environ['http_proxy']
    handlers.append(urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': url, 'https': url}))
```

I ran `unset http_proxy` to unset that environment variable `http_proxy` then the problem solved.